# Dump sql server 2008 database to XML

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xml-serialization, sql-server-2008-r2

I need a full dump of my SQL server database in one large XML file. I need to get all the tables, except on some tables I need to exclude specific columns, (columns with raw data).

How can I do this?

I am using SQL server 2008 R2.

Comment: What kind of XML are you expecting to get from SQL Server?  Do you have a specific form in mind?

Comment: I just need the tables width the data-type and data-value of each row in XML. I don't really have a specific format in mind.

Comment: I'm thinking of just querying the database in code(C#) and manually converting it to XML there.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried it, but I believe you can use the bulk export option of [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx):

From SQL Server Books on-line:

"E. Bulk exporting XML data
The following example uses bcp to bulk export XML data from the table that is created in the preceding example by using the same XML format file. In the following bcp command,  and  represent placeholders that must be replaced with appropriate values:

```
bcp bulktest..xTable out a-wn.out -N -T -S<server_name>\<instance_name>
```

"